# How to find the conditional variance?

Tags: statistics, variance, time-series

Suppose I have the following time series process with $a_t$ being an independent white noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$:

$$
z_t = \frac{1}{3}a_t + \frac{1}{3}a_{t-1} + \frac{1}{3}a_{t-2}
$$

How do I compute the variance conditional on $a_{t-2} = 5$

Also, the unconditional variance in this problem is $\frac{\sigma^2}{3}$ correct? Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for the variance (conditional or unconditional) of what? Of $z_t$?

Comment: Yes. The variance of $z_t$ conditional on $a_{t-2} = 5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\frac{1}{3}a_t$ has variance $\frac19\sigma^2$

$a_t,a_{t-1},a_{t-2}$ are mutually independent so

- $\mathrm{Var}(z_t)=\frac39\sigma^2=\frac13\sigma^2$
- $\mathrm{Var}(z_t\mid a_{t-2}=5)=\frac29\sigma^2$

Comment: So Basically since $Var(a_{t-2})$ is given we exclude it when calculating the variance of $z_t$ which is then just the sum of the variance of the other two random variables that were not given?

Comment: Yes - since the three are independent, fixing one removes its contribution to the variance of the sum but does not affect the others

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I calculate the $Cov[z_t,z_{t-1}]$?

Comment: $\mathrm{Cov}[z_t,z_{t-1}] $ $= \mathrm{Cov}\left[\frac{1}{3}a_t + \frac{1}{3}a_{t-1} + \frac{1}{3}a_{t-2},\frac{1}{3}a_{t-1} + \frac{1}{3}a_{t-2}+ \frac{1}{3}a_{t-3}\right] $ $= \mathrm{Var}\left[  \frac{1}{3}a_{t-1} \right] +\mathrm{Var}\left[  \frac{1}{3}a_{t-2} \right] $ $=\frac29\sigma^2$

Comment: You're real one. I greatly appreciate you!